# Database design - multiple many to many table

Tags: sql-server, database, database-design

After struggling with this 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37981463/nest-list-to-excel for hours, I started thinking if my database design is even right. I have multiple one to many relationship i.e. One table is related to multiple other tables

```
tblDocument - documentId(Pk) & other fields
tblArticles - articleId (Pk) & other fields...
tblNotes - noteId (Pk) & other fields ...
tblComments - commentId(pk) & other fields ...
tblRemovals - removalId(pk) & other fields ...
```

Above all are independent entities on its own and are related to tblDocument thought joining tables i.e One document can have more than one article, notes, comments and removal. It means I have another set of tables like this

```
tblDocumentArticles - id(pk), articleid (fk), documenetid (fk)
tblDocumentNotes - id(pk), noteid (fk), documentid(fk)
tblDocumentComments - id(pk), commentid (fk), documentid (fk) 
and same for the last table.
```

Every thing in tblArticles, tblNotes,tblComments and tblRemovals are pre populated multi selection. User can pick any combination. Now I have to get all related records for each DocumentId per line and export it to excel. User might have pick more than one articles, notes, comments or removals and that where I am struggling and that why I asked this question whether my database design is even right? I am using EF5 if it will make any difference..

I hope I am making any sense if not please free to ask any question I will appreciate it

Comment: Your question is not very clear. What is the difficulty you are having?

Comment: Since you have a one to many relationship you should NOT create a separate table to store the relationship. For example the relationship of one document can have multiple articles can be modeled by introducing the documentId in the tblArticles table. A separate table to store the relationship is usually created when you have a many to many  relationship. Getting your data in one line is just one of your application / presentation requirements. It should not influence your core database design.

Comment: @phonetic_man this is exactly my problem that i am not clear that it is one to many or many to many. I thought about putting documentid in tblarticles, but one articles can be attached to more than one document it means its many to many. that's why i have separate joining table. I hope i make some sense

Comment: @ZoharPeled my problem is i am not clear that how i can present this data. Suppose One document two articles and two notes and one comment. Now the result set i get doesn't show the right data.. i mean documentid 1 has article 2 and 3, and notes 1 and 2 , and comment 1 and i am getting each row per each separate record

Comment: @bankerbox. Just to be very clear you have the following situation. DocumentId1 can have multiple articles Article1 and Article2 and Article2 can also belong to DocumentId2. This is a many to many relationship. If this case is applicable to you then it makes sense to have a separate table to store the relationship.

Comment: @phonetic_man yes that's true. documentid1 can have multiple articles and article1 and article2 and article3 can also belong to document2 and so on..

Comment: @bankerbox, in that case your database design looks fine to me.

Comment: @phonetic_man thank you .. it means i got to do something about my query